# Can't call cygwin commands from R

Tags: r, cygwin

I'm working in windows box, and using cygwin to imitate unix shell. Also I have R and want to run any system comand from it. I believe that `system('command')` would do this, but it didn't work for each `'command'`. For example `system('ls')` returns `/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/ls: write error: Bad file descriptor` and I think that this is beacause R calls `ls >& -` which also returns same error. So how solve this problem?

Comment: How do you invoke R? Did you try to invoke R from within Cygwin and then break to the shell?

Comment: Have you tried using `shell` rather than `system`?

Comment: I have tried just now and it returns same error + one more
'ls' execution failed with error code 1

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. How exactly have you told Windows to use cygwin as the default shell?

Comment: what version of R? do you have Rtools installed? what version of Rtools?

Comment: @Fojtasek I have appended cygwin/bin path to PATH envvar.
@mdsumner I'm using R-2.8.1. Rtools is not instaled. Also I have tried in R.exe command line tool and it works, but it doesn't work via Rgui.exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are still interested in a solution. Here is what I have:

- Start R from Windows and call cygwin executable by path: `system('C:/cygwin/bin/ls.exe');`
- Start R from within cygwin:

  - Start cygwin
  - Set path: `export PATH="$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Programme/R-2.9.2/bin"`
  - Call R: `Rgui.exe`
  - Call shell: `system('ls')`

Regards,

Martin.