# How to call Cygwin command from R

Tags: r, shell, command-line, cygwin

I need some help with **calling Cygwin commands from R** (I use R-Studio, I work with Windows 7). Today I installed Cygwin for the first time and connected with Dropbox via e.g. the following command:

```
./dropbox_uploader.sh upload "kokon.jpg"
```

My question is: how to construct the R command to call these function from R console (via Cygwin)? Let me explain that I got familiar with the documentations of `system` and `shell` functions, and also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068264/cant-call-cygwin-commands-from-r) question, but I still keep getting confused with it.

Thank you in advance for being of some help.

Comment: https://github.com/karthik/rDrop might provide some useful approaches to this (overall) issuee

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

- invoke RStudio from cygwin
- find the shell script path in Windows and use that, invoking under cygwin's `env` from Windows' `CMD`.

The first option is not so good, as it will use a different path for all of your add-on packages, but it will work.

To use the second option, find the script with `dir /s <name>`.

For example, I create a script foo.sh, and want to run it.  I created it in my home directory, and find it with `dir`:

```
 C:\>dir /s foo.sh
  Volume in drive C is WINDOWS
  VOlume Serial Number is 442D-5D33

  Directory of C:\cygwin64\home\u8002287

12/01/2013  01:56 PM                 29 foo.sh
```

Contents of foo.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Invoked Foo"
```

Now to invoke, translate that Windows path to Cygwin, and explicitly invoke it under `env`:

```
system('cmd.exe /c c:\\cygwin\\bin\\env /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/u8002287/foo.sh', TRUE)
## [1] "Invoked Foo"
```

`env` is used here because it doesn't care if what you run is an executable or shell script or other script.

Comment: **Matthew**, thank you so much for your attention! Unfortunately, following your suggestions and running: `system('cmd.exe /c c:\\cygwin\\bin\\env /cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/Marta/dropbox_uploader.sh', TRUE)` results in message:  `[1] "/usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory"
attr(,"status")
[1] 127 Warning message:
running command 'cmd.exe /c c:\cygwin\bin\env /cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/Marta/dropbox_uploader.sh' had status 127` , while I **do have** a .sh script in a localization:  `C:\cygwin\home\Marta\dropbox_uploader.sh`. Do you suppose what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that `env` is finding the file `dropbox_uploader.sh` as it complains about not finding `bash`; presumably `dropbox_uploader.sh` is a bash script.  I do not know why `env` is not finding `bash`, presumably by the full pathname.  It works just fine on my Win7 system, whether the target script is invoked by sh, bash, or other.